# R outlier program

Tags: r, statistics, data-mining, outliers

I want to write a program for removing the outliers from my data set. This code shows the outlier rows and column number but it does not delete them from my data set:

```
library(outliers)
out <- outlier(Practice_data[,2:4], logical=TRUE)
out <- cbind(FALSE, out)
Practice_data[which(out[,], TRUE)]
which(out[,], TRUE)
```

So how can I delete these outliers from my data set and save them in another new data file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the rows that contains at least one outlier, try the following (the outlier function will identify the outliers in each dimension for you, it will not remove them, you have to remove them explicitly):

```
library(outliers) 
out <- outlier(Practice_data[,2:4], logical=TRUE) 
indices <- which(rowSums(out) > 0)
Practice_data <- Practice_data[-indices, ]
```

Comment: how can i remove this rows explicitly. Please give me the syntax.

Comment: it's already there in the above code, the last line removes the outliers identified.

Comment: It is showing the data in True and False. I want this data in my original number format not in True or False.

Comment: Try it now. It will give u what u want.